# Making use of json data inside QML

Tags: json, qt, qml

I'm trying to replace a text in my .qml file with a json data.
In my .qml file I have the following:

```
   Text
   {
       **text: qsTr("J1-25")**
       anchors.right: tc1.left
       anchors.rightMargin: 20
       anchors.verticalCenter: tc1.verticalCenter
       color: "white"
       font.pointSize: 10
   }
```

I created the .json file with the following info:

```
{
  "pwm":
    [
      {"id": "1", "pin": "J2-21"},
      {"id": "2", "pin": "J2-22"},
      {"id": "3", "pin": "J2-23"},
      {"id": "4", "pin": "J2-24"},
      {"id": "5", "pin": "J2-25"},
      {"id": "6", "pin": "J2-26"}
    ],
"truecurrent":
    [
      {"id": "1", "pin": "J1-21"},
      {"id": "2", "pin": "J1-22"},
      {"id": "3", "pin": "J1-23"},
      {"id": "4", "pin": "J1-24"},
      **{"id": "5", "pin": "J1-25"},**
      {"id": "6", "pin": "J1-26"}
  ]
}
```

How do I replace the text in my .qml with true current data in .json file (both in bold)?

```
JsonLoader {
    id: jsonLoader

    filePath: ":/example.json"

}

Text
{
    text: jsonLoader.jsonObject["truecurrent"]["5"]  //text: qsTr("J1-25")
    anchors.right: tc1.left
    anchors.rightMargin: 20
    anchors.verticalCenter: tc1.verticalCenter
    color: "white"
    font.pointSize: 10
}
```

Comment: Which JsonLoader are you using? Can you share a link to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript JSON parser. Here an example with a fixed string. You can load the string from file.

```
function getData() {        
    // TODO: get the json string from file
    let data = "{
        \"pwm\":
            [
            {\"id\": \"1\", \"pin\": \"J2-21\"},
            {\"id\": \"2\", \"pin\": \"J2-22\"},
            {\"id\": \"3\", \"pin\": \"J2-23\"},
            {\"id\": \"4\", \"pin\": \"J2-24\"},
            {\"id\": \"5\", \"pin\": \"J2-25\"},
            {\"id\": \"6\", \"pin\": \"J2-26\"}
        ],
        \"truecurrent\":
            [
            {\"id\": \"1\", \"pin\": \"J1-21\"},
            {\"id\": \"2\", \"pin\": \"J1-22\"},
            {\"id\": \"3\", \"pin\": \"J1-23\"},
            {\"id\": \"4\", \"pin\": \"J1-24\"},
            {\"id\": \"5\", \"pin\": \"J1-25\"},
            {\"id\": \"6\", \"pin\": \"J1-26\"}
        ]
    }"

    // parse with JavaScript JSON parser
    return JSON.parse(data);
}

property var jsonData : getData();

Text
{
    anchors.fill: parent
    
    // access JSON data entries
    text: "Pin: " + jsonData.truecurrent[5].pin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest` to load both HTTP and FILE resources. In the following, if I declare `data.json` and place it in the same folder as my QML source file, I can use `XMLHttpRequest` with a relative reference to pick it up. You will be required to set
"QML_XHR_ALLOW_FILE_READ" environment variable to "1" since without it, access to local files will be prevented in the latest versions of Qt.

Using this technique, you can create your own `JsonLoader` object as follows:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    id: page
    JsonLoader {
        id: jsonLoader
        source: "data.json"
    }
    ColumnLayout {
        spacing: 20
        Label { text: "pin" }
        Text
        {
            text: jsonLoader.jsonObject.truecurrent[5].pin // J1-26
        }
        Label { text: "json" }
        ListView {
            Layout.preferredHeight: contentHeight
            model: jsonLoader.jsonObject.truecurrent
            delegate: ItemDelegate {
text: `id: ${modelData.id} pin: ${modelData.pin}`
}
        }
    }
}

// JsonLoader.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Item { 
    property url source
    onSourceChanged: load(source)
    property string text
    property var jsonObject
    function load(url) {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url); 
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState !== XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                return;
            }
            text = xhr.responseText;
            jsonObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
}

// data.json
{
    "pwm":
    [
        {"id": "1", "pin": "J2-21"},
        {"id": "2", "pin": "J2-22"},
        {"id": "3", "pin": "J2-23"},
        {"id": "4", "pin": "J2-24"},
        {"id": "5", "pin": "J2-25"},
        {"id": "6", "pin": "J2-26"}
    ],
    "truecurrent":
    [
        {"id": "1", "pin": "J1-21"},
        {"id": "2", "pin": "J1-22"},
        {"id": "3", "pin": "J1-23"},
        {"id": "4", "pin": "J1-24"},
        {"id": "5", "pin": "J1-25"},
        {"id": "6", "pin": "J1-26"}
    ]
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)