# How do I read a local JSON file in javascript that is being run by Qt6 QML?

Tags: javascript, json, qt, qml

## Problem

I need to read a local JSON file from a JavaScript file which is being run by the QML GUI using XMLHttpRequest, but the problem is that it is not returning successful `onreadystatechange`, so the JSON is not being read.

## Code

The javascript code I am using to read the JSON file is:

```js
var json_read = new XMLHttpRequest();

json_read.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (json_read.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && json_read.status == 200) { // not getting past this part
       var json = JSON.parse(json_read.responseText)
       console.log(json)
    }
}

json_read.open("GET", "modpacks.json", true);
json_read.send();
```

## What I have tried

- I have made sure that the JavaScript code is being run correctly by the QML GUI
- I tried using `fetch()` to read the JSON but it is not supported by Qt 6
- I have made sure my JSON file is formatted correctly

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!
Note: I have check other similar questions but they are either not for Qt 6 so they don't work or their solution doesn't fix my problem. So this is not a duplicate.

Comment: if you don't get an answer then most likely there is a problem with your connection - server isn't available, network error etc. Try to test it with another server, try to use another client with your server etc. add some prints inside `onreadystatechange` to test readyState/status

Comment: Ah, just noticed the you need a local file. Did you read [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-xmlhttprequest.html#accessing-local-files) notice? [This](https://www.qt.io/product/qt6/qml-book/ch13-networking-local-files) example can be useful too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/76115662/881441

Comment: @StephenQuan @folibis I used the solutions you guys gave and figured that the problem is on the `JSON.parse` line. Turns out the XML request is giving a empty string from the responseText. But I do not know why this is happening I have checked that the json file is formatted correctly.

Comment: that shouldn't be a problem since you request a text (responseText), Maybe it could be because of the location. can you provide the JSON file so we can test it?